Scanner.readLine() with custom line delimeter
I have a string that needs to be read using the Scanner class from the beginning to the \n character. The problem is that the source stream in my case may contain the character \u2028. I know that the Scanner class uses the pattern "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]" to separate lines, for this reason scanner.nextLine() on input line:
1 2 3 4 5 '\u2028' 6 7 8 will only read 1 2 3 4 5
I think that if I could force the scanner to use the pattern [\n\r\u2029\u0085] (default scanner pattern without NEW_LINE symbol) that would solve my problem. How can I read the entire string ignoring the \u2028 symbol ?

Do you mean nextLine() instead of readLine()? Can't you use scanner.useDelimiter("[\n\r\u2029\u0085]") and then use scanner.next()?

@Ivar Brilliant and simple solution. I hadn't thought of that at all. Please format your suggestion as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you very much.

Hello Smetana, welcome, String newString = string.replace( "\u2028" , "" ); or String newString = string.replaceAll( "\u2028" , "" ); and work with newString?.

@MarcePuente I considered this solution, but it does not suit me, since I read hundreds of gigabytes of text information and then process it. So loading all the data from the stream into memory is not an optimal solution for me.

Is'nt this is why we can use .useDelimiter("\\R").  "\\R" Matches any Unicode line-break sequence, that is equivalent to \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029].

by the way, the somewhat simpler BufferedReader class has a readLine()...

The code of @Ivar Brilliant solution:
 String input = "1 2 3 4 5 \u2028 6 7 8\n9 10";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\n\r\u2029\u0085]"));
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String result = scanner.next().replaceAll("\u2028", "");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    scanner.close();

